# Show that $\partial x^2 = 2P(x)$ and $\partial \wedge x = 0$ (Geometric algebra)

Tags: geometric-algebras

Show that $\partial x^2 = 2P(x)$ and $\partial \wedge x = 0$ (Geometric algebra)I’m trying to show equations (2-1.32) and (2-1.33) on page 51 of 20 of Hestenes and Sobczyk’s “Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus”.

> $\partial |x|^2 = \partial x^2 = 2P(x) = 2x, \tag{1.32}$
> $\partial \wedge x = 0, \tag{1.33}$

In trying to obtain $(1.32)$, I used the definition $(1.2)$

> $a\cdot\partial F(x) \equiv \left.\frac{\partial F(x+\tau a)}{\partial \tau}\right\vert_{\tau = 0} = \lim_{\tau\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(x+\tau a)-F(x)}{\tau},\tag{1.2}$

along with equation $(1.5)$

> $\partial_x = P(\partial_x) = \sum_k a^ka_k\cdot \partial_x \tag{1.5}$

and the product rule $(1.24a)$

> $\partial(FG) = \dot \partial\dot F G + \dot \partial F\dot G, \tag{1.24a}$

where the overdot designates the quantities to be differentiated (with the remaining ones to be treated as constants), to rewrite $\partial x^2$ as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}\partial x^2 &= \partial (xx) = \sum_k a^ka_k\cdot\dot\partial \dot x x + \sum_k a^ka_k\cdot\dot\partial x \dot x \\ \end{aligned}$$

$$ = \sum_k a^ka_k x + \sum_k a^k\lim_{\tau\rightarrow 0}\frac{x(x+a_k\tau)-xx}{\tau} $$

$$ = P(x) + \sum_k a^kxa_k $$

But then, why is $\sum_k a^kxa_k = P(x)$?

Finally, how do I obtain $(1.33)$ from $(1.32)$ and the so-called *integrability condition*

> $\partial_x\wedge \partial_x = 0 \tag{1.29}$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_ka^ka_kx$ is not the same thing as $\sum_ka^ka_k\cdot x$. Instead,
$$
  \partial x^2 = \sum_k(a^ka_kx + a^kxa_k) = \sum_ka^k(a_kx + xa_k) = 2\sum_ka^ka_k\cdot x = 2P(x) = 2x.
$$
Better yet, if you know that $b\cdot\partial x = \partial b\cdot x = P(b)$ for constant $b$ then
$$
  \partial x^2 = \partial(x\cdot x) = \dot\partial(\dot x\cdot x) + \dot\partial(x\cdot\dot x) = 2\dot\partial x\cdot\dot x = 2P(x) = 2x.
$$

For $\partial\wedge x$ just directly apply the formula for $\partial x^2$:
$$
  \partial\wedge x = \partial\wedge\left(\frac12\partial x^2\right) = \frac12(\partial\wedge\partial)x^2 = 0.
$$
We can rebracket like this because $x^2$ is a scalar.

Comment: Can I argue that $b\cdot \partial x = \partial b \cdot x$ simply because I already have that $b\cdot \partial x = \partial x\cdot b$ and that the inner product of two $1$-vectors commutes?

Comment: @Rodrigo No, absolutely not. You are misunderstanding the bracketing. The usual convention in geometric algebra is for the geometric product to have the *least* precence, i.e. you always do it last. With parentheses my equation reads $$(b\cdot\partial)x = \partial(b\cdot x) = P(b).$$ The reason this is true is because, more generally, $$(b\cdot\partial)L(x) = L(P(b))$$ for any linear $L$, and $$\partial(b\cdot L(x)) = P(\bar L(b))$$ where $\bar L$ is the adjoint. The expressions $(b\cdot\partial)x = \partial(b\cdot x)$ are only equal because $x \mapsto x$ is the identity function.

Comment: I don’t see how I misunderstood the bracketing here. I meant $(b\cdot \partial)x = \partial (x\cdot b) = \partial (b\cdot x)$ because $x\cdot b = b\cdot x$.

Comment: @Rodrigo You said "I already have that $b\cdot\partial x = \partial x\cdot b$". How? It looks to me like you're saying $b\cdot(\partial x) = (\partial x)\cdot b$ which is true but irrelevant (in fact, both expressions are $0$). If you are really just saying that you already know $(b\cdot\partial)x = \partial(x\cdot b)$, then yes $x\cdot b = b\cdot x$ for any two vectors.

Comment: Yes, I meant I already knew $\partial (x \cdot b) = \sum a^k a_k\cdot \partial (x\cdot b) = \sum a^k a_k\cdot b = P(b) = b\cdot P(\partial x) = b\cdot P(\partial) x = b\cdot \partial x$. Nevertheless, thank you for posting $\partial (b\cdot L(x)) = P(\overline L(b))$.

Comment: How do you obtain $\partial (b\cdot L(x)) = P(\overline L (b))$?

Comment: @Rodrigo Expand $\partial = \sum_ka^k(a_k\cdot\partial)$, use the defining equation of the adjoint $b\cdot L(x) = \bar L(b)\cdot x$, and use the more fundamental relation $(a_k\cdot\partial)x = a_k$.

Comment: Isn’t the defining equation of the adjoint $\overline L(b) = \partial L \cdot b$?

Comment: @Rodrigo Perhaps that is how Hestenes and Sobczyk do it, but $b\cdot L(a) = \bar L(b)\cdot a$ for all vectors $b, a$ is the more standard definition of the "adjoint of $L$ under the symmetric bilinear form $\cdot$". They note this relation in Eq. (2.19b). You can derive it from their definition by dotting by $a$: $a\cdot(\partial L(x)\cdot b) = a\cdot\partial L(x)\cdot b = L(a)\cdot b$.

Comment: I see, so is the following a correct proof of $\partial(b\cdot L(x)) = P(\overline L(b))$? $\partial(b\cdot L(x)) = \sum a^k (a_k \cdot \partial)(\overline L(b)\cdot x) = \sum a^k (\overline L(b) \cdot a_k) = \sum a^k a_k \cdot \overline L(b)$, where the last equation follows because both $\overline L(b)$ and $a_k$ are vectors so that their inner product commutes?

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151698/discussion-between-nicholas-todoroff-and-rodrigo).